# How to loop over function arguments

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to figure out a good way to loop over function arguments. I have the code below, and I just brute forced it for three different cases, "3 point", "5 point", and "7 point". Each of these cases have corresponding variables such as "P_list_3point", "xpoints_3point", etc.

I know one way to simplify the code below is to create a function out of each "block" of code since they repeat the same process, but how would I then loop over the arguments? like each case (3 point, 5pt, 7pt) has a series of corresponding vectors, how do i automate inputting these vectors into the actual function? i'm only working with three cases, but what would be a good way to structure it if i was working with 1000? apologies for any nooby mistakes i'm still pretty bad at coding

```
T1 = 298 #incoming temperature, dummy value in K
P1 = 10 #incoming pressure, dummy value in atmospheres
M1 = 1.4349 #inlet mach number
gamma = 1.4


P_list_3point = np.zeros(len(xpoints_3point)) 
T_list_3point = np.zeros(len(xpoints_3point)) 
M_list_3point = ypoints_3point
for i in range(len(xpoints_3point)):
    P_list_3point[i] = SolveP(P1, M_list_3point[i], gamma)
    T_list_3point[i] = SolveT(T1, M_list_3point[i], gamma)
    
    
    
P_list_5point = np.zeros(len(xpoints_5point)) 
T_list_5point = np.zeros(len(xpoints_5point)) 
M_list_5point = ypoints_5point
for i in range(len(xpoints_5point)):
    P_list_5point[i] = SolveP(P1, M_list_5point[i], gamma)
    T_list_5point[i] = SolveT(T1, M_list_5point[i], gamma)
    
    
    
P_list_7point = np.zeros(len(xpoints_7point)) 
T_list_7point = np.zeros(len(xpoints_7point)) 
M_list_7point = ypoints_7point
for i in range(len(xpoints_7point)):
    P_list_7point[i] = SolveP(P1, M_list_7point[i], gamma)
    T_list_7point[i] = SolveT(T1, M_list_7point[i], gamma)
```

Comment: Your intuition that a function would be useful here is good! Have you tried to write a function that accepts one of your xpoint values and does those six line blocks?

Comment: "how do i automate inputting these vectors into the actual function?" You don't; you *pass them as arguments* when you call the function.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple way, if I understand your question correctly. I am assuming `xpoint_n_points, ypoints_npoint` are given.

```
def xPoints(xpoint_n_points, ypoints_npoint):
    length = len(xpoint_n_points)
    P_list_npoint = np.zeros(length) 
    T_list_npoint = np.zeros(length) 
    M_list_npoint = ypoints_npoint

    for i in range(length):
        P_list_npoint[i] = SolveP(P1, M_list_npoint[i], gamma)
        T_list_npoint[i] = SolveT(T1, M_list_npoint[i], gamma)
    return [P_list_npoint, T_list_npoint]
```

Comment: Thank you! You're correct, my question assumes that xpoint_n_points and ypoints_npoints are given.

Suppose i have xpoint and ypoint vectors from 3, 5, 7, going to some arbitrarily high number, is there any easy way to automatically group them and then pass them as arguments to the function you wrote?

off the top of my head i think creating an array could work where the array is continuously updated with the creation of each new xpoint and ypoint vector, but im wondering if theres a cleaner way

Comment: @Fil The function does not depend on number of points, so you can directly call it for each point. You might might need dictionary for grouping but it really depends.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a dictionary to represent each point variables:

```
# Create a dictionary to represent the lists
P_list = {}
T_list = {}
M_list = {}

def ProcessPoint(point):
    # Assuming xpoints, ypoints are also dictionary or you can convert it into dictionary
    P_list[point] = np.zeros(len(xpoints[point])) 
    T_list[point] = np.zeros(len(xpoints[point])) 
    M_list[point] = ypoints[point]
    for i in range(len(xpoints[point])):
        P_list[point][i] = SolveP(P1, M_list[point][i], gamma)
        T_list[point][i] = SolveT(T1, M_list[point][i], gamma)

# Then you can call the function for each points
ProcessPoint(3)
ProcessPoint(5)
ProcessPoint(7)
```